# Preserve custom changes done to JPA Entity after adding fields to table and regenerating

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipse-luna

In Eclipse I have a JPA entity that represents a table. I have added to the fields of the entity some Annotations and I have even created a few methods (like clone, equals etc.).

While I am developing the solution I find that I need to add a few more table columns; I have two ways to go forward. Either make the changes manually to the entity or just recreate the Entity and redo everything from scratch.

I was wondering if there is a better way to differentially add new fields of the entity or I am stuck with the two above solution.

In Doctrine 1.2 PHP there was the concept of a Base entity and the custom ones extended that but I am not sure for JPA.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion: create/add the new field(s) in the JPA entity, update `equals` and `hashCode` (if required)...and you should good to go. Generating an entity makes sense at the beginnings; once you have "something working" you **don't want to take any risk(s)**. On the other hand, it's also valid to regenerate it, just make sure you don't mess too much when you diff/commit changes.

Another point you should have in mind is: if one of the fields that you add cannot have a `NULL` value you should/must update your existing data to *normalize* that.